# Meteor - accessing parent template vars from child helpers

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, reactive-programming

I cannot get and set the parent template variable from within the child helper.
I have read plenty of pages on the issue but I'm stuck ...

```
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {  
    this.myVar = new ReactiveVar('xyz');
});
```

is expected to be accessible in child like this:

```
Template.child.helpers({
setAndGetIt : function() {
    Template.parentData(1).myVar = 'testString';
    return Template.parentData(1).myVar;

}});
```

where

```
<template name="parent>    
    {{>child}}  
</template>
```

Do I miss something? (Sessions solution is not a case here...)

Comment: btw, you can use Session instead ReactiveVar.

Comment: What I wrote in the question is ... Sessions solution is not a case here... :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed this

Answer (score 1):

There's a smarter way to accomplish this task. But you need to explicitly declare which variables you want to be accessible in the child template. and most probably you want that `var` to be reactive.

```
Template.parentTemplate.onCreated(function(){
    this.myVar = new ReactiveVar('hello');
});
```

in Blaze, you need to pass this variable when calling the child template like this.

```
{{>child myVar=myVar }}

Template.child.onRendered(function(){
    console.log(this.myVar.get());
});
```

Comment: First of all it's not working for me, "this.myVar" is "undefined". Second, I have to set the vaule from withing child helper

Comment: you need to add `reactive var` package first. and you can set/get the variable from anywhere.

Comment: It's added for sure, as we use it elsewhere